# Google Analytics request authorization

Tags: google-analytics

My gmail account has access to our GA platform, and I am able to query the data using a GA query tool available online. When I build a query string for a request on my own, I get the error "Login Required". Not sure where or how in the query string to put this info, or even what the credentials are.

Comment: And you've registered your application with google cloud console? Have you looked Google Analytics Magic Script - http://analytics.blogspot.com/2012/08/automate-google-analytics-reporting.html

Answer (score 1):

The regular GA API requires you to login. It spits out a login box on the page, even if you are doing it server-side. If you want to be able to do this without making it do this, you can use GA [superProxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy)